# Sentry on Angular working in localhost (serve) but not on a server(build)

Tags: angular, sentry

I'm trying to work with Sentry for Angular 8.

it's working great and capturing the error events when served in localhost, but not on a build on the server.

Would love any help to understand why/what's the difference I'm missing ?

```
//app.module.ts
Sentry.init({
    integrations: [new Sentry.Integrations.Breadcrumbs({
        console: false
    })],
  dsn: "https://somecode@o386725.ingest.sentry.io/sometoken"
});

@Injectable()
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor() {}
  handleError(error) {
    const eventId = Sentry.captureException(error.originalError || error);
    Sentry.showReportDialog({ eventId });
  }
}
//later added to providers
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: SentryErrorHandler }
```